# How to debug GNU make step by step?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gfortran, fortran90

I want to add a new fortran module into an existing fortran90 program. The existing fortran90 program is compiled by firstly running `./configure`, then run the `make` and `make install`. If I want to define my own innovation, what else I need to do is `export VER_USER=xxx`, then `make user` and `make installuser`. It seems that `make` does the compilation job and `make install` does the installation job. And I need to add something like `gfortran -o using_FKB using_FKB.o other.o ...  -L/path_of_lib -lnewlib` or `path/to/libneural.a`. So I need to debug the original `Makefile`. But I found it's difficult because the original `Makefile` is too long. I tried to use `make -V=1` or `make -d`, and also `make SHELL='sh -x'` , but they prints so much things on my terminal...I could hardly debug. Is there anyway to debug it step by step?

By the way, there are too much `$()` variable in the `Makefile`. When I use ``make -V=1`or`make -d`, and also` make SHELL='sh -x' `, I found they hardly print the command in` Makefile`like`$(OBJ_PATH)=/path/obj_path`...and it's quite hard for me to debug this...so is there any way to debug the` Makefile``` step by step? Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you have to determine is whether editing the makefile is the right thing.  If the package uses `configure`, then there's a good chance that the `configure` script creates the makefile, from a file `Makefile.in`.  And there's also a chance that the `Makefile.in` file was itself generated from a file named `Makefile.am`, if the project uses automake.  So you need to look and see if either of these two files exist before you can even decide where to start.  If `Makefile.am` exists you should edit that.  If `Makefile.in` exists you should edit that.  Else, edit `Makefile`.

Comment: Hi @MadScientist, thanks for your reply! I checked that there are no ```Makefile.in``` and ```Makefile.am```. There are just ```Makefile```, ```Makefile.SURFEX.mk```, and a lot of ```Rules.xxxxx.mk```, for example, ```Rules.LXgfortran.mk```, ```Rules.zgfortran.mk``` and ```Rules.zifort.mk``` and other ``Rules.xxxxx.mk```s...

Comment: Beyond what you have the only thing I can suggest is trying Remake: http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/  I have never used it myself but it seem to do the type of thing you want to do.  It's quite possible that, like using GDB, you will have to learn the basics of makefiles before you can get very far with it.